# Filling attributes in one field based on second field with same values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, update, grouping

How do I fill the attribute with `"SID_2"` of the captured image where the ID of `"SID_1"` is `NULL`?

I'm using QGIS 3.22

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? How did you achieve it in your example? How do you determine the order in your attribute table? Is there a logic which NULL is replaced with which SID?

Comment: Why not updating values like `"SID_1" = "SID_2"` ?

Comment: Currently, Excel is filling in the field.

The order of the properties table is sequence fields.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to *update `SID_1` with the value of `SID_2`* ***if* `SID_1` is `NULL`**

- choose `Update existing field` in the `Field Calculator`
- execute a simple conditional:

  ```
  IF( "SID_1" IS NULL, "SID_2", "SID_1" )
  ```

This will run an update on *all* rows in that table, albeit **with the desired result**. For small'ish tables this should be good enough - on very large layers you may want to pre-select features having a `NULL` value in `SID_1`.

Comment: You can also use `COALESCE("SO_1", "SO_2")`.

Comment: True. But both should compile to the same executor, and some verbosity may help at times ,)

Comment: I think the expression of the image caused a misunderstanding
I want to implement the value of sid_1 like sid_2.

sid_2 is the result value.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a short PyQGIS script. First create your new field e.g. `"ID_2"` and fill it with the values from `"ID_1"` (the expression to do that is simply `"ID_1"`).

Next open the Python Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), click the notepad icon to open an editor, copy and paste in the code below.

```py
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

fld_index = lyr.fields().lookupField('ID_2')

atts_map = {}

id = 1

for feat in lyr.getFeatures():
    atts_map[feat.id()] = {fld_index: lyr.getFeature(id)['ID_2']}
    if feat['ID_2'] == NULL:
        atts_map[feat.id()] = {fld_index: atts_map[id-1][fld_index]}
    id+=1
    
lyr.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(atts_map)
```

Note that I have copied the field names from your other question:

[How can we fill a property in QGIS 3.22?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/431123/how-can-we-fill-a-property-in-qgis-3-22)

So if your field names are not `"ID_1"` and `"ID_2"`, you should adjust accordingly.

Finally, make sure your layer is selected as the active layer and click the green Run button to run the script.

See images below for example results on a test layer.

Script pasted into editor:

[image]

Attribute table before:

[image]

Attribute table after:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Ben                                                                                                                          
 I applied it and it works well.
I'd like to use a modeler to do this. Can you make it work on the modeler? The reason why I use a modeler is because I want to do several repetitive steps at once.